# Javascript hide and show css

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML element with the class value of ".feedback-preview" I also have the CSS displaying it to none. I am trying to utilize Javascript to make the feature show. I am unsure what I am doing wrong code will be provided below.

Ideally what I am trying to replicate is there is a form and that the form should not show the preview or the submit button until information is inputted within the form. It is for a web development class I am taking. Thanks in advance I will display all of the code I am using.

```
document.querySelector(".feedback-from").textContent = "Faduma Egal";
document.querySelector(".feedback-content").textContent = "Do you allow pets?";

// Create Variables

var fromValue = document.querySelector(".feedback-from");
var feedbackValue = document.querySelector(".feedback-content");
var nameField = document.querySelector("#nameinput");
var feedbackField = document.querySelector("#other-info");
var form = document.querySelector(".contact-form");
var feedbackPreview = document.querySelector(".feedback-preview");
var submitButton = document.querySelector(".submitbutton");
//add text to preview section

function completePreview() {
    fromValue.textContent = nameField.value;
    feedbackValue.textContent = feedbackField.value; 
    feedbackPreview.className = "feedback-preview show";

    if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
        submitButton.className = "submitbutton show";
    }
}

completePreview();


// create event listeners for changes to form

form.addEventListener("change", completePreview, false);


/* CSS */ 

/* fieldset styles */
fieldset {
   margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}
legend {
   font-size: 1.25em;
}
.reserveinfo {
   position: relative;
}

.submitbutton {
   display: none;
}

/* field styles */
input, textarea {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   padding: 0.2em;
   font-size: 1em;
   display: block;
}
.contactinfo input, .additionalinfo input {
   width: 25em;
   margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}
textarea {
   width: 25em;
   height: auto;
}
#submit {
   border: none;
   padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: #e3d5ba;
   font-size: 1.25em;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

/* label styles */
label {
   margin: 0.8em 0;
   font-size: 1em;
   line-height: 1.6em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

/* feedback preview section */
.feedback-preview {
   max-width: 400px;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 2px solid black;
   font-size: 1.3em;
   background-color: white;
   display: none;
}

.show {
   display: block;
}

.feedback-preview p {
   margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}
.table-row {
   display: table-row;
}
.table-row div:first-child {
   font-weight: bold;
}
.table-cell {
   padding: 0 0.2em;
   display: table-cell;
}
.feedback-content {
   padding: 0.4em 0.2em 0;
}

/* footer section */
footer {
   max-width: 800px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0.6em 0;
   background-color: #34180f;
   color: ivory;
   text-align: center;
}

/* print styles */
@media print {
   body, h1, article, footer {
      color: rgb(0,0,0);
      background: rgb(255,255,255);
   }
   body {
      max-width: 100%;
   }
   nav {
      display: none;
   }
}
@page {
   margin: 0.75in;
}





<!-- HTML -->

<fieldset class="submitbutton">
               <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </fieldset>
         </form>
         <div class="feedback-preview">
            <div class="table-row">
               <div class="table-cell">
                  <p>To: </p>
               </div>
               <div class="table-cell">
                  <p>Phillip Blaine, Lakeland Reeds</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
               <div class="table-cell">
                  <p>From:</p>
               </div>
               <div class="table-cell">
                  <p class="feedback-from"></p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
               <div class="table-cell">
                  <p>Subject:</p>
               </div>
               <div class="table-cell">
                  <p>Feedback/question</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <p class="feedback-content"></p>
         </div>
      </article>
      <footer>
         <p>45 Marsh Grass Ln. &bull; Marble, MN 55764 &bull; (218) 555-5253</p>
      </footer>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One problem is that you are applying 2 classes, one with `display: block` and one with `display: none`. Perhaps your `.show` CSS definition should be `display: none !important;` to ensure you are overriding the `display: none`

Comment: please update complete HTML code...form html code is incomplete

Comment: are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BRRNQE